# jquery: access value of a textbox in datatable

Tags: jquery, asp.net, datatable

In a datatable, I added a textbox column **(2nd column)  by append**:

```
 var textbox= '<input type="text" class="txtBox">';
```

But now, I want to get the value of the textbox. I am doing this via:

```
 var row_index;

 $(document).on('mouseover', '#table1 tr', function() {
    row_index = this.rowIndex;
 });

  function getIncrement() {

    var dtable = $('#table1').DataTable();
    var textvalue = dtable.rows(row_index).cells(1).value; //textbox column is 2nd
    alert(parseFloat(textvalue));

  }
```

The problem is I am getting a **'NaN'** (Not a number) value. If I remove parseFloat, I am getting 'undefined'. Any ideas? Thank you in advance.

P.S. the row_index value in just fine. If I use alert to get its value, I am getting the correct index. Also, I have no problem getting the value of other row values using the index. I only have problem with the "txtbox" column. Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting value from a dynamically-generated DataTable input](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28464914/getting-value-from-a-dynamically-generated-datatable-input)

Comment: Instead of **dtable.rows(row_index).cells(1).value** you have to use DOM traverse find() function with the specified class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store `row` instead of `rowIndex` and later find the textbox within it  using [find()](https://api.jquery.com/find/). Once you get the element call [val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/) to get its value.

```
$(document).on('mouseover', '#table1 tr', function() {
    current_row = this;
});

function getIncrement() {
    alert(parseFloat( $(current_row).find(".txtBox").val()));
}
```